# How to pass java object to pentaho then parse then save to database

Tags: java, pentaho

I'm still searching on how to pass parameters like object to pentaho then parse the data and save it to db using pentaho.

Comment: Sorry to hear about that.

Comment: is there a way on how to do that? or do you know where I can see/look some examples?

Comment: What do you mean with Pentaho : Pentaho Analytic, Pentatho Data Integration?

Comment: Pentaho data integration.

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) parameters are string : you will have to serialize your object in a string before passing it to PDI.